# Enter data to a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I created a custom `UITableViewCell` (I created a class that extends `UITableViewCell`) and I created a xib file that contains my custom cell).Everything is working great but I have the following problem. I have created the custom cell with 4 labels, and I connected the labels to code in Xcode 4. When the function for creating the table is called I can't access labels. Here the code.
`

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView,MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    string cellIdentifier = "Cell";
    var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier);
    //cell = null;
    if (cell == null) {
        cell = new MyCustomCell();
        var views = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("MYCustomCell", cell, null);
        cell = Runtime.GetNSObject( views.ValueAt(0) ) as MyCustomCell;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to cast `cell` into an instance of your `UITableViewCell` implementation to access the custom properties and methods.

You may want to have a look at Miguel de Icaza's approach for customizing `UITableViewCells` and combine them with `UIViews` that are reusable outside of the cells.
You can find the article here: http://tirania.org/monomac/archive/2011/Jan-18.html

Comment: Where does Apple recommend not subclassing?   They even give some pointers to how to do it:http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Huh, you're right. I did not know that source. My last information was to add stuff to the content view is considered the best solution. I will update my answer. Thanks for the hint.